# How can I make sure that if a message is not consumed from a JMS queue, it should get deleted after a certain time?

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

I want the messages to get deleted from the JMS queue if they are not consumed within a certain time limit. What attribute or setting should I configure in while creating the queue?
I have tried expiry but even after the expiry time, I can see the message in the queue

Answer (score 0):

Some JMS implementations will expire messages on queue, but some drop expired messages when consumed. So even though you can see an expired message in the queue, it should not be received by any messages receiver.